# I want to run a python script via integrated terminal using Ctrl + Enter in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Suppose I have `foo.py`.

I have to right click `foo.py` -> Open as Integrated Terminal -> (in terminal, python foo.py)

Is there a way to Ctrl + Enter and it does the above.

And can you select a single function and run only that a bit like Jupyter notebook.

Comment: Please provide details. What OS? Do you work under VS Code explorer?

Comment: Its on Windows 10

Comment: Yes I work under VS code explores. Every time I have to run multiples files form different directory I have to do the above. Hoping there a is a shortcut for this.

Comment: Does it make sense to drag and drop files onto the terminal?

Comment: Not exactly what I wanted. The answers are for default execution not integrated terminal execution

Answer (score 1):

See the docs: [Keyboard Shortcuts editor](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_keyboard-shortcuts-editor)

The commands you're looking for are:

- Python: Run Python File in Terminal (`python.execInTerminal`)
- Python: Run Selection/Line in Python Terminal (`python.execSelectionInTerminal`)

Although note that they work differently: the first runs the file like you want, and the second one launches a Python REPL then runs the selection/line there.

Answer (score 0):

Install the [pycmd extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=insilica.pycmd) and add shortcut

```
{
        "key": "ctrl+enter",
        "command": "extension.pycmd",
        "when": "editorTextFocus && editorLangId == 'python'"
},
```

Then `ctrl+enter` will send the python expression following your cursor to the active terminal.

I made this extension and there are some edge cases that aren't perfect. I'm working on it, or you can contribute at https://github.com/insilica/vscode-pycmd